# Whats is difference if I include a space in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re

line = "Cats are smarter than dogs"

matchObj = re.match( r'(.*) are (.*)', line)

if matchObj:

    print ("matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2))
else:

    print ("No match!!")
```

When i run this code i get an ouput: `smarter than dogs`

But if put an extra space at the end of my my RE

```
matchObj = re.match( r'(.*) are (.*) ', line)
```

I get output as: `smarter than`

Can anyone explain why am i getting this difference in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're adding the extra space in `matchObj = re.match( r'(.*) are (.*) ', line)`, you're asking to match as many character as it can in `(.*)` followed by a space.

In this case it is `smarter than`, as the space character matches the space in `dogs`.

Without the space, the `.` can match any number of characters other than new line.  So it ends up matching until the end of the string, `smarter than dogs`.

Read the documentation on [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for more info.